# React form validation using state and ref not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a React form component that uses state and a ref to perform input validation before submitting. However, I'm encountering some issues where the error state is not updating correctly and the form still gets submitted even with validation errors.

I've tried console logging the values and I can see that the state and ref values are being updated correctly, but the form still goes through.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
import './register.scss';
import { useState, useCallback, useRef } from 'react';
import { isEmailCorrect } from '../../helpers/validations';

const Register = () => {
    console.log('Register rendered');


    const [error, setError] = useState([]);
    const [ok, setOk] = useState(false);
    const terms = useRef(undefined);

    const handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();

        setError(prevState => []);

        /**
         *  1 -> Primero miro si esta checked los terminos y condiciones         * 
         */

        if (!terms.current.checked) {
            setError(prevState => [...prevState, {
                'uuid': 'Client error',
                'message': 'Debes de aceptar los Terminos y condiciones!'
            }]);
        }
        /**
         * 2 -> Ahora trato todos los demas inputs
         */

        const formValues = [...event.target]
            .filter(({ nodeName }) => nodeName !== 'BUTTON'
                && nodeName !== 'FIELDSET'
            ).map(({ value }) => value);

        const vacios = value => value.length === 0;

        const body = {
            name: formValues[0],
            lastName: formValues[1],
            email: formValues[2],
            password: formValues[3],
            passwordRepeated: formValues[4],
        };

        if (formValues.some(vacios)) {
            setError(prevState => [...prevState, {
                'uuid': 'Client error',
                'message': 'No pueden haber valores vacios'
            }]);
        }

        if (!isEmailCorrect(body.email)) {
            setError(prevState => [...prevState, {
                'uuid': 'Client error',
                'message': 'El email tiene formato incorrecto'
            }]);
        }


        if (body.password !== body.passwordRepeated) {
            setError(prevState => [...prevState, {
                'uuid': 'Client error',
                'message': 'Las contraseñas no coinciden'
            }]);
        }

        //?? El valor de error esta vacio aunque haya hecho setError arriba?

        if (error.length == 0) {
            //hacer el fetch
            registerUser(body);
        }

    };



    const registerUser = useCallback((body) => {

        fetch('http://localhost:9000/users/register', {
            method: "POST",
            mode: "cors",
            cache: "no-cache",
            credentials: "same-origin",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(body)

        })
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {

                if (!('error' in data)) {

                    console.log("Data ok!" + JSON.stringify(data));

                    const { id, email, name, password } = data;
                    setError([]);
                    //!todo redirigir a la pagina de login
                    setOk(true);

                } else {
                    console.log("Error in data" + JSON.stringify(data));
                    setError(prevState => [...prevState, {
                        'uuid': 'Server error',
                        'message': data.error
                    }]);

                }
            });
    }, []);


    return (

        <div className='register-content'>
            <h1>Crear nueva cuenta</h1>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <fieldset>
                    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="First name" />
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <input type="text" name="lastName" placeholder="Last name" />
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset>
                    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email" />
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset className='passwords'>
                    <input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Password" />
                    <input type="text" name="passwordRepeated" placeholder="Repeat Password" />
                </fieldset>
                <fieldset className='terms'>
                    <label>Terms and conditions</label>
                    <input ref={terms} name="terms" id="terms" type="checkbox" />
                </fieldset>

                {
                    ok && <p style={{ 'color': 'green' }}>Te has registrado correctamente!</p>
                }

                {error.map((error, index) => {

                    const { uuid, message } = error;
                    return (
                        <p key={uuid + index} style={{ 'color': 'red' }}>{`${uuid}: ${message}`}</p>
                    );
                })}

                <button type="submit" >Crear nueva cuenta</button>

            </form>
        </div>
    );
};

export default Register;
```

Any ideas on what might be causing this issue and how to fix it?

Expecting a solution!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to access the `error` after setting the `error` state. Because of how React handles setting the state, you are not guaranteed to have the latest `error` state when you call `if (error.length == 0)...`. This is because the state will not be updated until after the component re-renders.
One solution could be to have a local variable in the handleSubmit function  `let hasErrors = false` which you update to true whenever you have errors. Then you can prevent submitting the form if there are any errors.

```
const handleSubmit = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
  let hasErrors = false;

  setError((prevState) => []);

  /**
   *  1 -> Primero miro si esta checked los terminos y condiciones         *
   */

  if (!terms.current.checked) {
    hasErrors = true;
    setError((prevState) => [
      ...prevState,
      {
        uuid: 'Client error',
        message: 'Debes de aceptar los Terminos y condiciones!',
      },
    ]);
  }
  /**
   * 2 -> Ahora trato todos los demas inputs
   */

  const formValues = [...event.target]
    .filter(({ nodeName }) => nodeName !== 'BUTTON' && nodeName !== 'FIELDSET')
    .map(({ value }) => value);

  const vacios = (value) => value.length === 0;

  const body = {
    name: formValues[0],
    lastName: formValues[1],
    email: formValues[2],
    password: formValues[3],
    passwordRepeated: formValues[4],
  };

  if (formValues.some(vacios)) {
    hasErrors = true;
    setError((prevState) => [
      ...prevState,
      {
        uuid: 'Client error',
        message: 'No pueden haber valores vacios',
      },
    ]);
  }

  if (!isEmailCorrect(body.email)) {
    hasErrors = true;
    setError((prevState) => [
      ...prevState,
      {
        uuid: 'Client error',
        message: 'El email tiene formato incorrecto',
      },
    ]);
  }

  if (body.password !== body.passwordRepeated) {
    hasErrors = true;
    setError((prevState) => [
      ...prevState,
      {
        uuid: 'Client error',
        message: 'Las contraseñas no coinciden',
      },
    ]);
  }

  //?? El valor de error esta vacio aunque haya hecho setError arriba?

  if (hasErrors === false) {
    //hacer el fetch
    registerUser(body);
  }
};
```